# Mysterious problem: Deleting massive amount of files doesn't free up disk space

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-usage, database

I have a disk that is 100% used, 400 GB of 400 GB, however I have moved more than 44 GB of files from it, but no extra space got available, the usage is still 400GB of 400GB.

```
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root            49G  5.1G   41G  12% /
udev                               32G  192K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs                              32G  148K   32G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda3                         158M   37M  114M  25% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_hana_backups  500G  471G   30G  95% /backup
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_B1H           200G   78G  123G  39% /hana/SAPBusinessOne
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_hana_data     400G   19G  382G   5% /hana/data
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_hana_log      400G  400G  280K 100% /hana/log
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_hana_shared   200G   35G  166G  18% /hana/shared
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_usr_sap       200G   45G  156G  23% /usr/sap
//10.1.1.201/HANABackups          1.9T  698G  1.2T  38% 
/windbackup/HANABackup
comapny-sap:/hana/log # du -h
1.3G    ./mnt00001/hdb00001
794M    ./mnt00001/hdb00003
286G    ./mnt00001/hdb00004
288G    ./mnt00001
288G    .
```

As it can be seen from lsof, there are no files still being held open by processes>

```
lsof -n | grep '(deleted)'
nautilus    6184       root   31r      REG              253,0       752    1753275 /root/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
nautilus    6184       root   32r      REG              253,0     32768    1753307 /root/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-bc638f00.log (deleted)
shutdown  111517       root    0u      CHR              136,0       0t0          3 /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
shutdown  111517       root    1u      CHR              136,0       0t0          3 /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
shutdown  111517       root    2u      CHR              136,0       0t0          3 /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
```

I have also tried copying 44 GB of files of that partition and than I could not copy any of the files from that 44 GB back, not even one 1 GB file?

Comment: If you are talking about the line - /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_hana_log      400G  400G  280K 100% /hana/log, you have 280 kilobytes available not gigabytes.

Comment: The problem is that du is reporting only 288 GB used, while df is reporting 400 GB used. Also when I remove files no space gets available and I can not put anything on that drive no matter that I moved more than 44 GB of data from it.

Comment: Your question is a different problem, and not a dupe in my opinion. But the problem as you say, is mystical - if there is 400gb allocated in an fs, and you delete 40gb, then 360gb will remain. The few exceptions are very rare (for example, hard links) and nearly surely don't happen in your case.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, run `du` before and after deleting all those files? (What were the results?)

Comment: @g-man yes I did and as I said du is reporting the size correctly, by that I mean reported size did shrink, however df size never goes down. Just a note the files are transaction logs for HANA database and they are about 1 GB in size. I thought at first HANA is keeping them opened but as you saw lsof is not reporting anything?

Comment: @peterh yeah I know but I am not sure if I can ask for a revision, this is also not the first time this happened to me on stack exchange.

Comment: @Dominik You have already 4 reopen votes, if you collect the fifth, your question will be reopened.

Comment: @peterh how to get that one vote? Any advice on that?

Comment: @Dominik You can try to consult on the chat, on the meta site. Ask them, what to do for their reopen vote, and do it. Or you can improve your question, for example I now gave a more descriptive title. The important thing is to make clear and easily understable, why your question is essentially different as the dupe.

Comment: @peterh thanks for that I will try the chat to see if smoothing can be done further